# How can I have a constant autoloaded when it does not follow the standard convention in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following class in a Rails 4 project:

```
app/components/x2xfoo/bar/klass.rb
```

with `klass.rb` being:

```
module X2XFoo
  module Bar
    class Klass
    end 
  end
end
```

The problem is that the Rails autoload mechanism does not find this constant:

```
$ bundle exec rails c
2.4.2 :001 > X2XFoo::Bar::Klass
NameError: uninitialized constant X2XFoo
    from (irb):1
...
    from bin/rails:8:in `require'
    from bin/rails:8:in `<main>'
```

Of course, if I change the content of the `klass.rb` file to define the module `X2xfoo` instead of `X2XFoo`, then loading the `X2xfoo::Bar::Klass` works ok, because it follows the standard Rails conventions.

But, is there a way to use the `X2XFoo` constant and have autoload work?

Answer (score 1):

Create or adjust `config/initializers/inflections.rb`:

```
ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections do |inflect|
  inflect.acronym 'X2XFoo'
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Update `config/application.rb` file to add `app/` directory to the auto load paths:

```
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/app)
```

Make sure you don’t manually require your new classes anywhere in the code. Let Rails restart & try this and see the magic.

That’s all. Your new classes should auto-reload now similar to rails default controllers, models, views etc.